# Efficient way to transport a Stargate

Tags: transportation, colonization, scientific-development

In the future Earth, scientists have successfully created [Stargate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stargate).

And because of the greedy nature of human being, they wish to colonize as many planets as possible!

And they sure can NOT wait till the [Warp Drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warp_drive) is invented!

So transporting Stargate to another planet become a huge problem!

Especially those planets of another star system!

So how could my scientific think tanks overcome this problem!?

**Additional Information:**

1. There is NO magic or superpower.
2. Based on as many scientific facts, realistic or fictional, as possible. But only technologies considered "lower" than the Stargate may be used. Of course this is all subjective, such as one could never know which of Stargete or Warp Drive is more advanced. But please do as best as you could to fit the criteria.
3. The scientists are controlled by greedy, and ignorant, governors, therefore simple answer such as "Our current technology is simply impossible to accomplish such a thing!" is ABSOLUTELY unacceptable!

**Update:**

Seems like a lot of comrades here have this question, so I decide to add it to the list.

4. Any objects moving in and out of the Stargate won't affect the gate itself at all! The device is simply open a connection between 2 different places. Not much unlike the regular door in your room.

Comment: You're asking what we call a [high concept question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4868), which isn't a good fit for our site. Ignoring the fact that the "stargate" franchise presumed a transportation system set up by a 3rd party using FTL ships (SG-U), you either have one trivial answer (it'll take a long, long time using conventional space flight) or no answer at all (the SG tech can't transport w/o 2 gates).  According to our [help/on-topic], Qs must be specific and answerable.  What specific and answerable problem do you have? What are your expectations for this Q?

Comment: @JBH Thanks for other people's answers, I already got some pretty good ideas for my setup! Thanks!

Comment: I got an idea, but it depends on an implementation detail: How does transfer of momentum work when an object moves through a pair of  stargates which move with different velocities and/or face different directions?

Comment: @Philipp The momentum should be remained related to the gate when you pass through it. Because otherwise it will be an unimaginable disaster when you're doing inter-planet travels such as from North Pole to Colombia! If the gate was facing the same direction of the Earth's rotation, you will fly right back through the gate and therefore make it impossible for you to pass the gate! And if the gate was facing opposite to the direction of the Earth rotation, you will fly out at the speed of roughly 1000 mph! And that won't be a pretty picture!

Answer (score 58, accepted):

**Rockets**

Rockets are the fastest means of acceleration we have but it's just not efficient but for a stargate, this isn't a problem as you can open the gate to refuel.

You effectively build the stargate into a ship and use the gate to refuel and resupply. Crew can come and go as wanted.

As tech improves, you bring it through the gate and upgrade the ship on the way.

With current tech, we're looking at around 100 years but with a gate, we don't need to carry supplies so the weight is less which means we can go much faster.

Comment: As for engine type: probably Ion engine, since it's the only one with a decent mass-to-propulsion ratio, and we can assume that fusion reactors at least have already been invented. EDIT: whoops, looks like mas doesnt matter, since we have a functioning stargate at our ship

Comment: In addition to fuel for the ship in transit, [parts for] another ship and stargate could be sent through, and once fully assembled you have two ships already in transit, and thus able to go to different final destinations in a similar sector of space.
Keep "splitting" ships in this way as fast as you can manufacture and assemble further supplies, and you only ever needed a single launch from earth's surface...

Comment: This idea is awesome. Instead of putting fuel tanks on the rocket, you can put fuel pipes through the stargate, and keep it open all the time.

Comment: Pipes might not work, depending on how "Stargate-like" the gates are. A Stargate stargate can remain open for 38 minutes at most. You'd have to make the pipes retractable.

Comment: Assuming you can arrange constant acceleration by piping fuel through the stargate, you could potentially get your ship to alpha-centauri in around 4 or 5 years at 1G. If you can sustain better than 1G, reduce time accordingly.

Comment: @EagleV_Attnam - Reminder: the Stargate franchise Gates are not real-time and do not allow for things like pipes to be pushed through partially to connect on the other side. (We see this in Season 1: Ep 11, The Torment of Tantalus. Ernest Littlefield's diving suit gets its hose cut when the gate transported him and shut down) You'd need to send fuel in barrels, or maybe put the the pipes up against the interface and use a high-pressure pump to overcome the stargate's restrictions on liquids. (this would possibly leak a bit, but that's an engineering challenge more than a real problem)

Comment: If you use a project Orion engine, you use small nukes as fuel. No need for pipes

Comment: +1 for voiding the rocket equation.

Comment: @Ruadhan - You can't get to Alpha Centauri in less than 4 years because it's about 4 light years away.

Comment: @Pere That's not entirely accurate. You cannot *send* anything to Alpha Centauri in less than ~4.4 years, but, with an acceleration of 1g, you can *get* to Alpha Centauri in about 3.6 years. Such a trip will take 6 years Earth-time, with a maximum velocity of ~95% c. (Fun fact: 1g is actually enough to cross all 93 Gly of the Universe in ~50 years.) I don't know how relativity may affect stargates, but it may be advisable to go slower than this speed to avoid any accidents. I used [this calculator](http://nathangeffen.webfactional.com/spacetravel/spacetravel.php) for these numbers.

Comment: Good point, You whip past Alpha Centauri at 95% of the speed of light around 4 or 5 years into a 1G flight. The real question is what happens when you have an infinite massless fuel-supply on a ship that definitely has mass and an engine capable of significant ISP... What happens when that ship just keeps accelerating up to and past the speed of light? Basically, is it progressively more difficult to make a fast moving object go faster for a given change in velocity? Relativity is a confusing subject.

Comment: Now all I can think about is a gas station employee standing next to the stargate, holding the nozzle, lazily staring at the counter going up.

Comment: Make sure you store ample amounts of consumables (food, oxygen, spare parts, etc.) on board. There should also be at least two gate experts on board at all times. If the gate stops working for any reason, the ship has no fuel, no resupply, and no way to call home.

Comment: In fact, given that this will be a years-long, high-stakes mission built upon technology that is new and therefore unreliable, you might want to have two gateships flying together. That way you have full redundancy, and if something goes catastrophically wrong on one ship, the other ship can rescue them. If there are aliens in your universe, you might also want an armed escort.

Comment: @HTNW Where did you get "93 Gly of the Universe" from? I am not aware of any models of the universe or changes to astronomy that place any figure of 93Gly on anything.

Comment: @Aaron The universe is ~14 Gyr old. Because the universe is expanding, the observable universe has a radius larger than 14 Gly. The current diameter of the observable universe is ~93Gly, and we are at the center of that diameter, by definition. [See Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observable_universe)

Comment: @ DawnPaladin - No you don't. Crew come and go as needed, they don't live on the ship. You don't store all the materials. If something happens to the gate, you are down a ship but not the lives of the crew. If you're worried about the gate breaking, you have a backup gate. If both gates are broken then something catastrophic happened to the ship.

Comment: @Steve with this idea of a "seed ship", the original ship will never need to stop. It can continues accelerating until it nears 1C and then keep dropping other seed ships along the way to slow down and land on planet. Would still take 100,000 years to seed the galaxy, but eventually it can be done once your first few ships are zooming around at near light speed.

Comment: @Sonvar - Can someone say Stargate Universe?

Answer (score 12):

It seems your only option is to utilise slower-than-light travel to get your Stargate to the each world you wish to connect to. Once it's there you can dial it up and use the wormhole to start sending through people and supplies to establish a colony. Once that's established you can start using that as a jumping-off point for the next Stargate seeding mission.

**Notes:**
Depending on if the Stargates have a minimum connection distance like the did in the show, it may be possible to use them to drastically boost the efficiency of your space program. Simply have one in orbit around Earth and push the ships through from the ground level. Bam! No need to waste all that fuel escaping Earth's gravity.

Similarly having one on the Moon, or at the edge of the Solar system allows you to shortcut the more expensive parts of space travel.

You may also be able to use the Stargate as a thruster depending on the exact physics. Have the engines on Earth where they can be easily refuelled and repaired, and direct their thrust through the wormhole here -

- If matter travelling through the gate exerts an equal and opposite force on it, you can put the 'gate at the rear of the ship and direct the thrust away to push yourself forward.
- If there is no corresponding force on the exiting 'stargate, you'll have to direct the thrust at the ship itself, and use an armoured catching plate or sail to absorb the force and push the ship forward - as well as the Stargate, as there is no force acting on it. Basically [laser propulsion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_propulsion).

IIRC correctly on the original show it was possible to connect to a ship in space as long as its position was calibrated correctly. In the show I don't think the Stargate thruster idea was ever attempted.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't quite understand your third paragraph under the notes. How could "**Simply bolt it to the back of your ship, ...**" help out in this situation!?

Comment: @PiggyChu The way I interpret that, is that the heavy engines and fuel remain on Earth, but because the reaction mass is being forced through the stargate, it actually provides impulse to the opposite stargate.

Comment: @ArkensteinXII I think this is similar to the situation "Bolt a fan on a sailboat and blow the sail". I don't know if it will work.

Comment: @ArkensteinXII would it actually provide impulse,  we never see any indication stargates impart or recieve inertia to thing passing through their portal. It could be used as an infinite fuel tank however.

Comment: Yeah, I'm suspicious of the physics as well.

Comment: Having a stargate in the ship (instead of on the back) makes it so it doesn't have to be a generation ship or be massively huge to carry food and people. Crew and new supplies can be taken to the ship at will, simplifying the ship.

Comment: The physics is a little screwy - tends to get that way around wormholes. If there is no equal and opposite reaction on the opposing Stargate, you can still use it as a thruster - just direct the output of the Stargate at the ship itself and use a "catcher plate" to absorb the force. Still a net thrust to the ship. Mightn't want to try it with a full rocket engine though.

Comment: @PiggyChu001 The physics is only non-workable if the matter coming through the stargate imparts an "equal and opposite" force on the gate itself. If it does, then "fan on a sailboat" is accurate because the fan pushes the boat backwards as much as it pushes the sails forwards and there's no net force. If the gate isn't being newtonian about it, then it's more like following the sailboat around with a fan and keeping it at a consistent distance from the sails.

Answer (score 8):

You said that when an object passes through a pair of stargates, then its velocity will also be transferred. So with some applied orbital dynamics and multiple pairs of stargates which you send through each other, you might be able to reach some really impressive speeds.

1. Create a pair of large stargates (1A and 1B).
2. Place 1A on a very large orbit around the Sun (somewhere in the Kuiper belt).
3. Accelerate 1B on a retrograde orbit around the sun which is slightly smaller than that of Earth. (a retrograde orbit is an orbit going the opposite direction of Earth)
4. Build a slightly smaller pair of stargate (2A and 2B) which fit through the stargate pair 1A and 1B.
5. Launch 2A from Earth in a prograde orbit which intersects that of 1B stargate. It will meet the larger stargate with approximately twice the orbital velocity of Earth, approximately  200,000 km/h.
6. When 2A enters 1B with 200,000 km/h, it will exit the outer stargate 1A at the same speed of 200,000 km/h. You saved most of the energy it takes to leave the Sun's gravity well.

With that speed it will arrive at Alpha Centauri in about 1000 years. That's still far too slow to meet our shareholder's expectations. But wait, the nice thing about this setup is that we can chain it!

We still got gate 2B back on Earth. If we put this one on a retrograde orbit too and send a 3rd, even smaller, stargate 3A through it, it will get launched out of 2A with another 200,000 km/h. You can chain more and more subsequently smaller gates that way. Each one gets you an additional 200,000 km/h. If you chain 10 stargate pairs like that, you get down to 100 years. If you chain 100 stargate pairs, you get down to 10 years (at that point you will experience diminishing returns due to relativistic effects. No matter how the physics behind your stargates work, this trick won't allow you to accelerate objects beyond the speed of light).

Just don't forget that you still need to decelerate when you reach the destination. But you can do that the same way if you rotate one of the gates in transit by 180°.

And if you can somehow disassemble the stargates before you fit them through and then assemble them after arrival, then you might even use stargates which are all the same size.

Answer (score 3):

> And because of the greedy nature of human being, they wish to colonize
>   as many planets as possible!

So we're trying to min/max time, so the rate limiting step is the speed of light and the vast distances between planets.

> Any objects moving in and out of the Stargate won't affect the gate
>   itself at all! The device is simply open a connection between 2
>   different places. Not much unlike the regular door in your room.

Accelerate a star gate to near light speed by using light sails, rockets, or whatever.  This is expensive resource wise but it only needs to happen once per "exploration" gate because we're never going to decelerate.

When the gate gets close to a system, do NOT decelerate but just drop another gate and exploration ship out of the first one.  This assumes gates are either not round or of differing sizes but presumably you can build the things so can influence that.

The 2nd gate and colonization force appear at their own velocity not connected to the 1st gate, they go down to the planet and explore it (hopefully colonize it) while the 1st gate continues on to another planet.

If the planet is unworkable then the colonization force returns home through the 2nd gate (this doesn't prevent using the 2nd gate as a jump off point).  If it is workable they stay.

Comment: When you step out of a fast moving stargate you are still moving fast. Your set is more like a door in a speeding train than a door in a bedroom.

Comment: @Pere Speed of exit in a stargate is weird, and shouldn't be expected to follow our intuition.  I'm assuming, since we have the ability to build gates in this thought experiment, that we also have some ability to control whether exit momentum is relative to the entering gate or the exit.

Comment: In Wordbuilding anything can be assumed. However, in the series they can walk in and out of Stargates even if they are in different planets which are moving at very different velocities.

Answer (score 1):

If we're talking about the initial endeavor to get a single "nearby" planet colonized and set up with a stargate, then I agree with other answers. If you rule out any tech as or more advanced than the stargate and warp drives, you are probably going to have to do it the old fashioned way with slower-than-light travel.

Regarding how to settle as many worlds as quickly as possible, you might consider adding some naturally occurring wormholes. Many works of science fiction rely on "wormholes" as shortcuts to other areas of the universe (sure, it stretches science a bit, but it's a well accepted sci fi trope). If you are lucky enough to have one or more stable wormholes in your neighborhood, you could use these naturally occurring "stargates" to get your ships and stargates to other parts of the universe, and then head for any planets close (galactically speaking) to the wormholes using traditional slower-than-light travel. This would give you access to more worlds faster and allow you to begin creating expanding hubs of colonized worlds with stargates more quickly than you otherwise might.

For instance, in David Weber's *Honorverse* books, the Star Kingdom of Manticore happened to be located at a terminus of multiple wormholes. This allowed them fast travel to several other areas of space, and made a tiny single star-system kingdom super rich as a result, because they became a hub of trade. In your case, the stargates would render the wormholes obsolete eventually, but the wormholes could still be used to get them places while you're getting your stargate system set up.